# Java TimerTask Execution Period

Tags: java

Can I overload the Java Timer Task to have it execute every one day?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.schedule(new SendEmailTask(), 6000000, 86400000);  //schedule to run one day?
```

Will there be no problem if I implement below period?

Answer (score 1):

the timer will execute the `SendEmailTask()`  after a delay of  6000000 ms and then every 86400000 ms, starting from the  time your application starts to run.

you are not overloading **the** timer  your are merely using an instance of **a**  timer.

it goes without saying that if your application is not running your timer event wont execute as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the timer to run once every day at exactly the same time of day? If so, try `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` (the `Timer.schedule` method will expire a specified `period` after the previous expiry; `scheduleAtFixedRate` expires a specified `period` after the initial delay.

Comment: Hi, 

This is what I would like to do..  I want my timer task to run once everyday on exactly the same time of the other day.

So If I used scheduleAtFixedrate, there will be no problem even if my period is equivalent to one day?
Will I not run into any problem even if I have a great value of period?

Comment: As far as I know java.util.Timer should work with large periods.

Comment: Hi Ash and Alon, Thank you very much for taking time out in answering my question...